# Using array and fit to curve changes orientation of object

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to make a simple stadium/arena and thought I could just make one section and use an array to fill the rest of the circle but when I try this it turns it sideways and renders it useless.  I've tried different origins, different offsets different deformation axis and it only makes it worse and not better.  I do not understand what I am doing wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaking, Blender uses the world's Y axis as reference to align your object to the curve. Something like that.

So theoretically, you would only need to rotate your object at a 90° angle (or -90°) on the world's Z axis. Maybe also apply the object's rotation via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

Nice demo picture by the way!

Comment: I think it's rather the X axis, but yes, rotating on the Z axis is the solution

Comment: Or maybe it's Y axis for particles. Or bones' Too many axes system to remember x)

Comment: as you see on his pictures, the door point out towards the X axis, and when its object follows the curve it follows the same direction

Answer (score 0):

1. **If** , in your illustration of the single element, the gizmo shows the Local axes of your object, the *Array* should be offset in Y, not X.
2. (The origin of your object is the point in the array-elements that will lie on the circle, shift the mesh in Edit mode, if not happy)
3. Again, with athe assumption in (1), the deformation axis in the *Curve* modifier should be Y, not X.